# View notification big style on click instead of opening it

Tags: android, notifications, onclick, action

I'm trying to make my Android notification to show its big view when clicking on it the first time, and then run another pending intent (start the app for instance) on the second click.

But let focus on the first need.
Instead of starting my app when I click on my notif, I want to show its big style, which contains action buttons.
From those action buttons, I can already do stuffs without having to start my app =) And then the notification is (automatically?) killed (which is ok).

Next, when the big style is shown, if the user click another time on it, i want  to start my app (which should not be a problem).

I want to do that since I noticed that people don't know that we can swipe down a notification to have a big style (if available)...

I don't want to set my notification priority as PRIORITY_MAX, but I want to prevent the user to go inside the app if the action buttons are enough for him.

What I was thinking to do, was to use the setContentIntent of the NotificationCompat.Builder to start a BroadcastReceiver, which will then recreate the notification with PRIORITY_MAX (to make sure we see the big style)... But it's not really nice to do this way, and I won't even be sure that the notification is not already in big view style before....

---

To make it maybe clearer, here is a simplified summary:

```
Notif normal --> on click (or swipe down) --> Notif big view (with action buttons)

Notif big view --> on click --> start the app
```

---

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible, unfortunately. (If you set your notification to the highest possible priority, Android might expand it by default, but that's the only thing you can do AFAIK)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well it's what I'm afraid of :( Now I'm thinking, maybe I can have a custom big view with an event on the main click, and a normal view I can only expand :) I'll check that!